# My code returns 0 for every output while calcualting weekly pay

Tags: c

I have intitalized the rate per hr(bpr) as 12.My aim was to find the gross pay,taxes and net pay given the no of hours entered by the user.Also if the hrs are more than 40 the rate increases by 1.5.So the rate for the extra hrs is 18ph instead of 12.Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    //program to calculate weekly pay

    int hrs = 0;
    int bpr = 12;
    double gross_pay = 0.0;
    double tax = 0.0;
    double net_pay = 0.0;

    printf("Enter the no of hours worked in a week: ");
    scanf("%d", &hrs);

    if (hrs <= 40)
        gross_pay =(bpr * hrs);
    else
    {
        gross_pay = (bpr * hrs);
        double overtimepay = (hrs - 40) * (bpr * 1.5);
        gross_pay += overtimepay;
    }


    if (gross_pay <= 300)
        tax = (0.15 * gross_pay);

    else if (gross_pay > 300 && gross_pay <= 450)
        tax = ((0.15 * 300) + 0.2 * (gross_pay - 300));
    else
        tax = ((0.15 * 300) + (0.2 * 150) + 0.25 * (gross_pay - 450));

    net_pay = (gross_pay - tax);

    printf("The gross pay is: %d\n",gross_pay);
    printf("The total tax amount is: %d\n",tax);
    printf("The net pay is: %d\n",net_pay);


    return 0;

}
```

The code return 0 for every output.Where is the fault?

Comment: This is beside the point, but you're calculating overtime pay incorrectly.

Comment: @FiddlingBits Sorry,edited the post to provide the missing infromation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are invoking *undefined behavior* by passing data having wrong type to `printf()`.

`%d` is for printing `int`, but you are passing `double`.

To print `double` via `printf()`, you should probably use `%f` or `%g`. (There are also some other specifiers to print `double` in different formats)